# Display attachments for each list item

Tags: list, spservices, attachments

I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]
Each list item have attachments (at least 1).

For now I have code which display all attachments with titles but I don't know how to modify this code to get desired result. This is what I get:
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Repozytorium",
        /*CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",*/
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

            var output = "";
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                $().SPServices({
                    async: false,
                    operation: "GetAttachmentCollection",
                    listName: "Repozytorium",
                    ID: id,
                    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                        $(xData.responseXML).find("Attachments > Attachment").each(function(i, el) {
                            var $node = $(this),
                                    filePath = $node.text(),
                                    arrString = filePath.split("/"),
                                    fileName = arrString[arrString.length - 1];


                            var liHtml = "<li><a href='"+ filePath +"' target='_blank'>" + fileName + "</a></li>";
                            //output += "<a href='" + filePath + "' target='_blank'>" + fileName + "</a><br />";
                            $("#drop-zone").append(liHtml);
                        });

                    }
                });

            });

            //$("#drop-zone").html(output);
        }
    });
});
```

It is simple I know but my knowledge of jquery is limited :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "State",
        /*CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",*/
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

            var output = "";

            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                var liHtml = "<div style='width:150px; position:relative; float:left;'><h5>"+title+"</h5>";
                $().SPServices({
                    async: false,
                    operation: "GetAttachmentCollection",
                    listName: "State",
                    ID: id,
                    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                        liHtml += "<ul style='list-style: none; width:140px; padding-left:5px;'>"; 
                        $(xData.responseXML).find("Attachments > Attachment").each(function(i, el) {
                            var $node = $(this),
                                    filePath = $node.text(),
                                    arrString = filePath.split("/"),
                                    fileName = arrString[arrString.length - 1];


                            liHtml += "<li><a href='"+ filePath +"' target='_blank'>" + fileName + "</a></li>";
                            //output += "<a href='" + filePath + "' target='_blank'>" + fileName + "</a><br />";

                        });
                        liHtml += "</ul></div>";


                    }
                });
                $("#drop-zone").append(liHtml);
            });

            //$("#drop-zone").html(output);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try updated it is perfectly match with your requirement.